# Unable to set auto deploy directory on Liferay Portal 6.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am working with Liferay 6.0 on JBoss 5.1.1, Windows 8 is the OS. On server startup I always get the following error explaining the auto deploy directory can't be found:

```
ERROR [AutoDeployDir:90] Directory F:\liferay-portal-ee-6.0\deploy could not be created
```

This makes sense because I don't have an F: drive. However, I'm unable to configure it in the `portal-ext.properties` file as explained [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/advanced-liferay-configurati-4). When I log into the Liferay control panel, and look under Portal Administration -> Portal Properties, I can see that the value I put in `ext.properties` is indeed displayed as the value for `auto.deploy.deploy.dir`. However, when the server starts up, it is using `F:\liferay-portal-ee-6.0\deploy` as the auto deploy directory and logging the error above. I have debugged the `GlobalStartupAction` class which initializes Liferay's auto deploy and I can see that it's calling `PrefsPropsUtil.getString(String, String)` to retrieve the value for the auto deploy directory and it's passing the value I set in `portal-ext.properties` as the second argument, according to the [PrefsPropsUtil Java doc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PrefsPropsUtil.html) the second argument is a default value.  When I dig down into the `PrefsPropsUtil.getString` call I can see that it's using an instance of `PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl` to retrieve a list of properties by `companyId`, `ownerId` and `ownerType` which are set to 0, 0 and 1 respectively.  Since the `PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl` is "local" I'm assuming it's not going to a different machine to retrieve values.  I've done extensive directory and file searching for references to `auto.deploy.deploy.dir` and values like `F:\liferay-portal-ee-6.0` and I'm unable to fine where this property is getting set. Where is this value coming from and why isn't my override being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Liferay 6.0, go to Control Panel-> Plugins Installation -> Install More Portlets -> Configuration.

In the configuration tab, you may see the Deploy directory set to be F:\liferay-portal-ee-6.0\deploy

This may be because either someone has modified the value from the control panel or you are using database dump from some other existing Liferay installation.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a ton of time searching the UI.

Comment: It seems auto deploy only works if I set it up in the Liferay control panel. I would like to configure auto deploy using the portal-ext.properties but when I remove the auto deploy directory values from the Liferay control panel, it doesn't use the values I've entered in portal-ext.properties. Do you know how I can get Liferay to use the auto deploy directory I set in portal-ext.properties?

Comment: Once you have set auto deploy directory from control panel, it will always use the value of control panel. As you had rightly debugged earlier it uses PrefsPropsUtil which first checks if there is a value for the property in database, if yes then use it else use the default value from the property file. Since you have already set the value from control panel, the value is persisted in database and that is what it will use. The only option if you want the value to be read from property file is to carefully remove the record from database.(Please take backup before doing any such thing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **auto.deploy.dest.dir** property in **portal-ext.properties** to set auto deploy path.

i.e

```
auto.deploy.dest.dir=C:/../../autodeploy
```

HTH