# Auto deploy Liferay portlets in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

how do you automatically deploy Liferay portlets in Netbeans? Every time I build a project, have to copy .war file to Tomcat deploy directory in Liferay. Is it possible to deploy .war file automatically, when project is built?

Comment: Check that app server related properties(auto.deploy.dir) in build.username.properties file of your plugin sdk are correct.

Comment: @PankajKathiriya thank you for response, but where is build.username.properties? I don't use liferay plugin sdk. I have java ee maven project and use spring portlet mvc.

Comment: Using maven you don't neet ant "auto.deploy.dir" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What deployment system are you using?
SDK or Maven?

If SDK, then create a file named build..properties inside your SDK root folder (note that  must be replaced with your OS user username).
In that file just set the absolute path of your application server

```
app.server.dir=/absolute/path/to/your/liferay/tomcat-x.x.xx
```

If you are using Maven, in your pom file be sure you are setting following (global or in-profile) properties:

```
<properties>
    <liferay.version>x.y.z</liferay.version>
    <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>/absolute/path/to/your/liferay/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
    <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>/absolute/path/to/your/liferay/tomcat-x.x.xx/lib/ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
    <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>/absolute/path/to/your/liferay/tomcat-x.x.xx/webapps/ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I use Maven. I tried to add these properties to pom.xml and also to .m2/settings.xml, but it didn't help. Here is my pom.xml http://pastebin.com/mj9H3n05

Comment: If "/Users/usr/Desktop/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga3/deploy" is your autodeploy folder, please make sure your LR is scanning that folder for new plugins to deploy (in portal properties by control panel)... then using "mvn liferay:deploy" are you sure that your war is copied in that folder?

Comment: Where can I find these properties? I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559327/unable-to-set-auto-deploy-directory-on-liferay-portal-6-0 and there is said "Control Panel-> Plugins Installation -> Install More Portlets -> Configuration". I use the last version of Liferay 6.2-ce-ga3 bundled with Tomcat. When I open "Control Panel" i don't see "Plugins Installation", there is only "Plugins Configuration", but there isn't deploy directory settings.

Comment: In 6.2, user interface is very different. Login as admin, then from dock: admin -> control panel -> server administration -> properties -> portal properties and search (by textfield) for what you need (e.g. "depl")

Comment: When I use "mvn liferay:deploy", the .war file is copied to deploy folder in liferay. Thanks for help.